# Cartoon show that was about magic stones and fighting with monsters

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

What I remember was that it had (its really vague but its all I got):

- Three or four main characters, one of them a girl, two of them guys, then there was like a dad or grandpa helping them.

  - They have magic stones they use to capture creatures, or they live inside the gemstone things.
  - The main character had some kind of blue and white bear/beast creature called "furrock" or something he had horns too.
  - The girl has some kind of rhino with nature powers, so it was covered in leaves.
- The main characters' dad was probably the evil guy; I can't remember

  - It was from around 2009-2011, I think.
  - It was on Netflix when I saw it, but since then its been deleted for a while.

I know it is not Huntik.  I'm just saying that cause that's what a lot of the searches thought it was but it's not. I know this isn't a lot but if someone knows anything it would be really helpful because I keep remembering and forgetting what its called.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You've got a nice set of details here, but it's possible that you might remember something else if you check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking good questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is definitely [Magi Nation,](https://magination.fandom.com/wiki/Magi-Nation_%28TV_series%29) as you can see from this picture

[image]